# HTTPWebServer PIO Naive

Tags: c++, webserver, native, esp32, platformio

I would like to be able to run the program I have from ESP32 natively on the platform, but I can't find libs that do the same thing or similar in native mode, I use Littlefs and HTTPWebServer, not necessarily the libraries have to be exactly the same with the same functions because I can create one and convert to another... but I've really been research

I found some libraries but they were very difficult to execute, I wanted something simpler that can be encapsulated inside a cassa to translate to the same methods as ESP32.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.